# Today i found this in my water bottle can someone please translate this gor me nd tell me that what is this gor?

Tags: quran, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, islamic-scholar, quran-translation

[image]

Found this tavez in my water bottle

Comment: It is illegible, from the few parts that I could barely decipher it seems to be Surahs al-Fatihah, al-Ikhlas, al-Falaq and Al-Nas.

Comment: I could decipher the following surahs in the order: al-Fatihah (how ever it seems that some words are misplaced or missing), al-Kafirun, al-Ikhlass. an-Nas, al-Falaq (incomplete). They are written in an inacceptable manner since Arabic words can't be divided, however, the author did. Further, the author concluded al-Fatihah writing "main" which is not qur'an.